# How to Implement file upload using CKEDITOR on YII2 PHP Framework?

Tags: yii, yii2, ckeditor

I am new to the YII2 PHP framework. I want to implement Ckeditor in my TextArea. I got the library, but try to find an upload file using CKeidtor. I didn't get any idea how to implement file uploading in CkEditor. [Library For CkEditor](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget)

Comment: you mean adding image in editor?

Comment: Yes. Can you help me please?

Comment: did you tried using clicking on image icon? it ask for url

Comment: That doesn't upload the image on server. Just show dialog box only. We have to code on that/ I am confuse how to do that.

Comment: https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget/issues/14
Please read this issue. SO that you have idea how to upload image on server. I am new on YII2 so i didn't get any idea what they have discuss.

Comment: try this `<?= $form->field($model, 'email_content')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
  'clientOptions' => [ 'filebrowserUploadUrl' => Url::to(['ckeditor/url']) ],
        'preset' => 'full'
    ]) ?>` it will show you upload option and you need to write upload action your own

Comment: "you need to write upload action your own" i am confused on this part. How to write action code??? Confusing part for me.

Comment: `public function actionMyAwesomeUpload() { ...`

Comment: `public function actionUploadfile(){ //file upload code here }` Uploadfile is name of your action (say function )  which contains file uploading code

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for the solution or for other people. 2amigos built an amazing [Library](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget) for ckeditor in Yii2. To implement it with image upload option you should set it like below:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'yourParameter')
         ->widget(CKEditor::className(), 
            [
              'options' => [], 
              'preset' => 'custom',
              'clientOptions' => [
                  'extraPlugins' => '',
                  'height' => 500,

                  //Here you give the action who will handle the image upload 
                  'filebrowserUploadUrl' => '/site/ckeditor_image_upload',

                  'toolbarGroups' => [
                      ['name' => 'undo'],
                      ['name' => 'basicstyles', 'groups' => ['basicstyles', 'cleanup']],
                      ['name' => 'paragraph', 'groups' => ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ]],
                      ['name' => 'styles'],
                      ['name' => 'links', 'groups' => ['links', 'insert']]
                  ]

              ]

            ]) 

?>
```

Now because you have to build the image upload handler yourself, here is an example of how you should do it.

```
public function actionCkeditor_image_upload()
{       
    $funcNum = $_REQUEST['CKEditorFuncNum'];

    if($_FILES['upload']) {

      if (($_FILES['upload'] == "none") OR (empty($_FILES['upload']['name']))) {
      $message = Yii::t('app', "Please Upload an image.");
      }

      else if ($_FILES['upload']["size"] == 0 OR $_FILES['upload']["size"] > 5*1024*1024)
      {
      $message = Yii::t('app', "The image should not exceed 5MB.");
      }

      else if ( ($_FILES['upload']["type"] != "image/jpg") 
                AND ($_FILES['upload']["type"] != "image/jpeg") 
                AND ($_FILES['upload']["type"] != "image/png"))
      {
      $message = Yii::t('app', "The image type should be JPG , JPEG Or PNG.");
      }

      else if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']["tmp_name"])){

      $message = Yii::t('app', "Upload Error, Please try again.");
      }

      else {
        //you need this (use yii\db\Expression;) for RAND() method 
        $random = rand(0123456789, 9876543210);

        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upload']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        //Rename the image here the way you want
        $name = date("m-d-Y-h-i-s", time())."-".$random.'.'.$extension; 

        // Here is the folder where you will save the images
        $folder = 'uploads/ckeditor_images/';  

        $url = Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl($folder.$name);

        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $folder.$name );

      }

      echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction("'
           .$funcNum.'", "'.$url.'", "'.$message.'" );</script>';

    }


}
```

Now because of CSRF-Token issue, the plugin can have problem sometimes. To solve it you can deactivate the CSRF Token only on this action like below:

```
 public function beforeAction($action)
{            
    if ($action->id == 'ckeditor_image_upload') {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

The Image option is now ready to use.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. i will check it tonight. For your effort -> up vote.

Comment: @NcitCosmos Can you provide the error message in your console or in your Network Panel?

Answer (score 0):

For those who, as I did, looking for complete guide of file uploading with CKEditor (based on Francis's solution).

First of the wall, you should use [2amigos widget](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget) to get your life easier.

Render that widget in the view you want to contain CKEditor:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'YOUR_FIELD_NAME')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
    'preset' => 'full',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'filebrowserUploadUrl' => '/CONTROLLER_NAME/upload',
        'filebrowserBrowseUrl' => '/CONTROLLER_NAME/browse'
    ]
]);
?>
```

In code above, I've used full preset, you can use any one you like (or customize it with 'custom' value).

> Note: you should attach your controller name in url strings, so it can be used both create and update actions

---

`'filebrowserUploadUrl' => 'upload'`

Here you should type name of action which will process file uploading. Francis do great job with example, so I can only say it should return JSON with such format:

```
//In case of success:
return [
                'fileName' => $NAME_OF_THE_FILE,
                'uploaded' => true,
                'url' => $URL_TO_SHOW_THE_FILE,
            ];
//In case of error:
return [
            'error' => [
                'message' => $MESSAGE_TEXT,
            ],
        ];
```

If your action will return anything but that JSON - it will show you alert with 'undefined' or 'Incorrect server response' message.

---

`filebrowserBrowseUrl' => 'browse'`

If you don't want to let users to browse uploaded files - just remove that line from widget options.

In other case you should add actionBrowse method to your controller, which will render page to browse and select images.

Controller method:

```
public function actionBrowse(){
    //get function num to pass it to the view (need to be called to pass data of selected file to CKEditor)
    $CKEditorFuncNum = Yii::$app->request->get('CKEditorFuncNum');

    //get list of uploaded files 
    $files = yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles($PATH_TO_FOLDER);

    return $this->renderAjax('browse', [
        'funcNum' => $CKEditorFuncNum,
        'files' => $files,
    ]);
}
```

> Note: that view will be opened as modal dialog, so I prefer to use renderAjax instead of render function to avoid rendering layout. But I'll not recommend you to use renderPartial if you want to use asset bundles

View file:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;

\backend\assets\AppAsset::register($this);

?>
<div class="container">

<h1><?= Html::encode(Yii::t('common', 'Choose any file')) ?></h1>

<?php if (!empty($files)): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ($files as $file):
            $url = "/$file"; ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
            <img 
                src="<?= $url ?>" 
                class="img-thumbnail" 
                style="cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 2rem"
                onClick="selectImage(<?= $funcNum ?>, '<?= $url ?>')"
            />
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectImage(funcNum, url){
        window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, url)
        window.close()
    }
</script>
```

`selectImage` function here will call CKEditor function to pass image url to file upload modal and then close modal dialog.